# display applet via javascript createElement

Tags: javascript, applet, createelement

Trying to take an existing  tag and instead display the applet using javascript to render the markup instead of having it hardcoded on the page.
   I first tried just using document.writeln() to write out the applet tag instead but that didn't seem to work at all.
   I then tried using createElement both for an object or an applet. The closest I have come to getting it working is below, where the java tries to load the applet, but can't find the class to load, so I *think* its something to do with the codebase and/or archive parameters.
   How the applet tag looks hardcoded:

```
                                <applet width="150%" height="394"
                                codebase="/applets"
                                archive="applet1.jar, applet2.jar"
                                code="aaa.bbb.Applet.class"
                                id="myapplet" name="myapplet" alt="My Applet"
                                style="background-color:#CCCCCC">
                                <param name="parm1" value="xyz" />
                            </applet>
```

closest I have gotten it to work via createElement:

```
        var applet = document.createElement('applet');
    applet.width='150%';
    applet.height='394';
    applet.codebase='/applets';
    applet.archive='applet1.jar,  applet2.jar'
    applet.code='aaa.bbb.Applet.class';
    applet.id='myapplet';
    applet.name='myapplet';
    applet.alt='My Applet';
    applet.style='background-color:#CCCCCC"';


    var urlParam = document.createElement('param');
    urlParam.setAttribute('name','parm1');
    urlParam.setAttribute('value','xyz');       
    applet.appendChild(urlParam);

    var appletDiv = document.getElementById("AppletDiv");
    appletDiv.appendChild(applet);
```

This at least tries to load the applet (on Firefox 38.2.1) but fails with ClassNotFoundException .. again think it has something to do with the codebase and/or archive specification.

I tried .setAttribute(name,value) instead of applet.name=value but that didn't fix it and in fact didn't even get the message about applet loading.

Also, I can't use any external code to render this so can't embed js code from another site.

I can also display the applet via the object tag as seen below, but again couldn't even get it to try to load the class creating the element as an object:

```
                        <object id="myapplet" name="myapplet" width="150%" height="394"
                            codebase="/applets" archive= "applet1.jar, applet2.jar"
                            classid="java:aaa.bbb.Applet.class">
                      <param name="parm1" value="xyz" />
                      xyz
                    </object>
```

Comment: [`applet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/applet) has been obsoleted for a while ago ...

Comment: yes, but this was the closest I got something to actually try to run .. tried as createElement('object') and never even got as far as trying to load the class ...

Comment: found out if I got rid of applet.codebase and instead prepended /applets/ to each of the archives .. it now works ..